# Do recursive functions carry over data once it repeats?

Tags: python, recursion, python-requests

Let's say I have a script in python that is using the requests module. It does a series of steps like posting data and going through multiple requests.

At some point in the script an error is raised and excepted, and the function reruns under the except recursively; that is, the function runs in the `except` block.

When that recursive function runs again, does the data that was transmitted from the previous run of the function carry over into the next? I noticed that after the function completed completely, the amount of times it recurred printed back with errors in terminal.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but the bottom line is "there is no magic".  At all.

Comment: Can you please give a code example such that you intend to let your recursive function carry over data?

Comment: Yeah, this depends on the recursion you're doing.  I would argue that it wouldn't unless you explicitly carry some kind of state over through the method calls (which would naturally beg the question "why", but I can't ask that until I see code).

Comment: Would be helpful if you could [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52958844/edit) and include the errors in the terminal into the question, so we can see the errors too.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't keep any state the previous call to the function had. If there is local data of the function you need to share between calls, you should pass it to the function as parameters.

However, every call to that function has the same scope. Any data kept outside the function available to it, will be shared between recursive calls. Example:

```
s = "Hello"
def fact (x):
    s = "Bye"
    v = x
    if x == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return x * fact (x - 1)
```

There, the first call to `fact` will change the value of `s` and it'll change for all function calls (and for any other place where `s` is used). But, when you call fact recursively; the variable `v` is not equal to `x + 1` before it's set in that call, it doesn't exist in that scope yet. If you wanted to keep it, `fact` should receive it as a parameter.

About the errors being printed: take into account that when you call a function recursively, the caller "instance" of the function doesn't end. It won't end until the recursive call ends, the "control" of the program goes back to that particular instance that made the call and it finishes normally.

Check this article out for a better explanation, specially the call stack section.

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-recursion-works-explained-with-flowcharts-and-a-video-de61f40cb7f9